# Insufficient Access when Deleting Custom Object or Tab

Tags: custom-object, error, metadata, ant, summer-15

I'm trying to delete an Object (not a record) in Salesforce. When using ANT I receive this message:

```
1. objects/myObject.object -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.
```

When using the UI and clicking delete, I receive this message:

```
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.
```

This also happens when I try to delete the `CustomTab` for the object as well. I suspect that deleting the `CustomTab` is a part of deleting the `CustomObject`.

A few other details:

- I'm on the default Sysadmin profile
- There aren't any master-detail relationships for this object, or any lookup relationships to this object.
- Occurs on Summer '15 (API 34.0), but not on Spring '15 (API 33.0).

  - This could be a red herring, the Spring '15 sandboxes had no data in them.

Where else could I look to figure out what is preventing this tab or object from being deleted?

Comment: In this case, I would check the Sharing settings of the custom object in the Security Controls. Though you are on the default Sysadmin profile, you can have a look who has created that object and what is your role. This is just a way to help you figure out whether this might be impacting your access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by this Known Issue:

[Deleting a Custom Tab or Custom Object throws an Insufficient Privileges error when the object has List Views created by other users](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YjgAAE)

This is scheduled to be resolved in Summer '15 Patch 8.0.